# C++ why is my default constructor only being called in one place but not other?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class with a static counter which is called in the default constructor and a class with a regular counter that holds a list of said objects with a dynamically created array.
When I add a new object to the array, the counters work fine, but if I create a new object outside of the list, then add it, xCounter increments twice.

I assume it has something do to with the line with the `<----- HERE -------` comment, but I don't understand why it increments an extra time while the first += call doesn't. Can someone explain why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X
{
    static int xCounter;
public:
    X() { xCounter++; }
    ~X() { xCounter--; }
    static int XCount() { return xCounter; }
};

class Y
{
    int yCounter;
    X* collection{ nullptr };
public:
    Y() {}
    int YCount() const { return yCounter; }
    Y& operator+=(const X& item)
    {
        X* tempCollection = new X[yCounter + 1]; // <----- HERE -------

        for (int i = 0; i < yCounter; i++)
            tempCollection[i] = this->collection[i];

        tempCollection[yCounter] = item;

        delete[] collection;
        collection = tempCollection;

        yCounter++;

        return *this;
    }
};

int X::xCounter;
int main()
{
    Y y;
    y += X();

    cout << "\nyCount: " << y.YCount() << endl;
    cout << "xCount: " << X::XCount() << endl;

    X x;
    y += x;

    cout << "\nyCount: " << y.YCount() << endl;
    cout << "xCount: " << X::XCount() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
yCount: 1
xCount: 1

yCount: 2
xCount: 3
```

Comment: You should be printing `this` when constructing and destroying your object, so that you see the instances being created.  Also, it is almost pointless, unless this is a classroom exercise, of trying to keep track of instance counts.  The compiler is free to optimize away constructor calls, plus you failed to track copy construction.  Therefore the number of destructor calls, may not match the number of constructor calls.

Comment: `y += X();` creates one object owned by the `y` and the temporary `X` is immediately destroyed. `X x; y += x;`: `x` is only destroyed when `main` goes out of scope, `Y::operator+=` creates 2 objects of type `X` and destroys one, i.e. at that time both `main` and `y` each own one more `X` than they did before. Btw: You should definetly initialize the variables `X::xCounter` and `Y::yCounter` to prevent undefined behaviour. @PaulMcKenzie there are circumstances where constructor calls may be optimized out, but this is not the case here.

Comment: Be aware of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @fabian how would I go about replacing one of the new X objects with the one initialized in main()? (`X x`)

Answer (score 0):

In line 48, you define `X x;` this calls `X`'s default constructor. That is the difference here.

Also, please initialize `yCounter`. Now it is uninitialized, so you will read garbage from it.

Edit: `X()` also creates an `X` object, but that is destroyed before the print.